# I keep getting #VALUE! when using my VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a code that takes the name of a filter and returns its price. The prices are in a separate workbook, in column A of the external workbook I have all the names of the filters and in row B their prices. I want my code to find the name of the filter and return the value of the cell next to it (its price). I've been going over my code for two days and can't find the issue, Excel keeps returning the #VALUE! error.
I even tried commenting the line that closes the external workbook and found that it isn't even opening it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```vb
' Takes the value from a cell and looks it up in the external workbook to retrieve its price

Function GetPriceFromOtherWorkbook(searchValue As String) As Long

    Dim otherWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim otherSheet As Worksheet
    Dim filtroColumn As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim price As Long
    
    'Check if the seach value is not empty
    If searchValue <> "" Then
        
        ' Open the other workbook
        Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\maras\Downloads\Denken\Lista_Precios.xlsx")
        
        ' Set the other sheet in the other workbook
        Set otherSheet = otherWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        ' Set the range to search in column A of the other sheet
        Set filtroColumn = otherSheet.Columns("A:A")
        
        ' Search for the value in column A
        Set foundCell = filtroColumn.Find(searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues)
        
        ' Check if the value is found
        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
            ' Get the corresponding price from column B
            price = otherSheet.Cells(foundCell.Row, otherSheet.Columns("B")).Value 'Assumes the price is in the next column (column B)
        Else
            MsgBox "Value not found in the other workbook."
    End If
        
    ' Close the other workbook
        otherWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Else
        MsgBox "Search value is empty. Please provide a valid value."
    End If
    
    'Return the price
    GetPriceFromOtherWorkbook = price

End Function
```

Comment: UDFs called from a cell are very limited in what they can do. You need to use a workaround to open a workbook.

Comment: Why not a simple VLOOKUP:  `=VLOOKUP(searchValue,'[C:\Users\maras\Downloads\Denken\Lista_Precios.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,FALSE)`

Comment: @ScottCraner but wouldn't i have to have open the other workbook all the time for the VLOOKUP to work?

Comment: no.  it will link to the other workbook just fine.  You will need to okay refreshing the links on each open. Only Volatile functions like INDIRECT and OFFSET require the workbook open.